# Transcription of a formula into a code

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a very long formula in excel, in fact is so overgrown that excel won't accept any arguments more. I thought of moving everything to a macro then...only that I'm less than basic when it comes to VBA. Would someone be able to advise if/how below part of my formula can be transformed into a code?

```
=IF(OR(AND(G6="Reputation_and_Credibility",I6*J6>I7*J7,I6*J6>I8*J8,I6*J6>I9*J9,I6*J6>I10*J10),
AND(G7="Reputation_and_Credibility",I7*J7>I8*J8,I7*J7>I9*J9,I7*J7>I10*J10),
AND(G8="Reputation_and_Credibility",I8*J8>I9*J9,I8*J8>I10*J10),
AND(G9="Reputation_and_Credibility",I9*J9>I10*J10),
G10="Reputation_and_Credibility"),
"Preference for safe delivery options",
```

I've been struggling with it for some time now and am close to giving up!

Thanks in advance.

PS I don't mean Worksheets("xxxx").Range("K6:K495").Formula = type of thing as it doesn't solve the problem :)

**Edit:** It seems I found my way to do this, most probably not the best one but a working one :)

```
Sub Risk_Appetite()

If Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value _
And Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value _
And Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value _
And Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value _
And Range("G6") Like "*Reputation*" Then
Range("M6").Value = "Preference for safe delivery options that have a low degree of inherent risk and may only have limited potential for reward"

ElseIf Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value > Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value _
And Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value > Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value _
And Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value > Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value _
And Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value > Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value _
And Range("G7") Like "*Reputation*" Then
Range("M6").Value = "Preference for safe delivery options that have a low degree of inherent risk and may only have limited potential for reward"

ElseIf Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value > Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value _
And Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value > Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value _
And Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value > Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value _
And Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value > Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value _
And Range("G8") Like "*Reputation*" Then
Range("M6").Value = "Preference for safe delivery options that have a low degree of inherent risk and may only have limited potential for reward"

ElseIf Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value > Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value _
And Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value > Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value _
And Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value > Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value _
And Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value > Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value _
And Range("G9") Like "*Reputation*" Then
Range("M6").Value = "Preference for safe delivery options that have a low degree of inherent risk      and may only have limited potential for reward"

ElseIf Range("G10") Like "*Reputation*" _
And Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value > Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value _
And Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value > Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value _
And Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value > Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value _
And Range("I10").Value * Range("I10").Value > Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value Then
Range("M6").Value = "Preference for safe delivery options that have a low degree of inherent risk and may only have limited potential for reward"

Else: Range("M6") = "Not_adequate"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure someone is going to work through all those IF, AND, &  OR statements to generate your code for you. Just use the `If`, `And`, & `Or` functions built into VBA to get the same results you have in your formula.

Comment: Try referencing [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx).

Comment: 2 suggestions: 1) with these gnarly complex formulas, it's often easier (to write, understand, & maintain) if you break the formula up into multiple steps. That also gets around the max formula limit. 2) if you'd like help with creating a VBA function, then can you please add an explanation as to what this formula is supposed to accomplish, as well as some sample data or a screenshot? If you have any code, then please post that as well.

Comment: Hi, I know...it's rather long and tangled. I tried this: If Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I7").Value * Range("J7").Value _
    And Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I8").Value * Range("J8").Value _
    And Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I9").Value * Range("J9").Value _
    And Range("I6").Value * Range("J6").Value > Range("I10").Value * Range("J10").Value _
    And Cells("G6") Like "*Reputation*" Then
    Range("M6").Value = "Preference for safe delivery options"
    
    ElseIf ... but I get Invalid Procedure Code or argument error?

Comment: Please update your question with the VBA code you've used.

Comment: Hi Chickesp, I have looked into this and it can be done in a far more simple manner by adding a couple of extra columns in your excel table. Would you appreciate a formula-based solution? If so, I will happily post one.

Comment: Can you show some values so we know what we are dealing with here? A screenshot of the worksheet would be great.

Comment: There are mismatched `()` and a function ending with a `,`. Please fix the code above. It is best to have as much _working code_ as needed in a question.

Comment: This question has been put on hold by some users, which I don't understand entirely as no one is forced to answer questions that seem too complex. But I'm new here, so maybe I'm missing something. Thank you for your help though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this in Excel without using VBA by making use of simper formulae. I have assumed your data is in a table of sorts resembling the following:

```
   G                            H    I          J
5  Reputation_and_Credibility?  ?    Number1    Number2
6       
7       
8       
9       
10
```

To calculate what you have in your formula in a simpler way, put the following formula in cell K6:

```
=I6*J6
```

To calculate the product of these cells, then drag down. put this formula in cell L6:

```
=MAX(K6:$K$10)=K6
```

This will calculate whether the product calculated before is greater than any other product below it. Drag this down the cells - note that the dollar symbols are very important such that the range can change depending on the cell the formula is in.

Finally, to emulate the last step of your formula at the top, enter the following formula wherever you want:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(G6:G10,"Reputation_and_Credibility",L6:L10,"TRUE")>=1,"Preference for safe delivery options",0)
```

I have put '0' as the false response of the IF statement as you did not provide one, so set this to whatever you need it to be.

Hope that helps! Mike

Comment: Hi MikeyB, thank you for this idea. I'm using this to calculate the score in M6 (merged 6:10) =IF(AND(I6*J6=0;I7*J7=0;I8*J8=0;I9*J9=0);" ";IF(AND(I6*J6>=I7*J7;I6*J6>=I8*J8;I6*J6>=I9*J9);I6*J6;IF((AND(I7*J7>=I8*J8;I7*J7>=I9*J9));I7*J7;IF(I8*J8>=I9*J9;I8*J8;I9*J9)))) because end users need one score with some conditional formatting applied, but maybe I can use embeded COUNTIFS to reduce the whole formula and then hide the additional column. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Hi Chickesp, how did it go? Did it work?

Comment: Hi MikeyB, I ended up with: IF(AND(G6="Compliance_Legal_Regulatory_Contractual_Policy",(K6=MAX(K6:K10)),K6>0),"Avoidance of risk...",IF etc. for each of 5 options as =MAX(K6:$K$10)=K6 would return TRUE every time I*J<>0. But your suggestion lead me to the final version, thanks again!